# How to change the syntax to get the next number instead of the previous?

Tags: pine-script

THE PROBLEM IS IN THE IMAGE BELOW

[SEE THE IMAGE AND THE PROBLEM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sU8Jk.png)

I want to change this part of the problem

HERES THE CODE

```
study("Weis Wave Accumulation", shorttitle="wwa", overlay=false)
Bandsize=input(75.0, type=float, minval=0.0)

//Direction
dir =0.0
//Central line
central = 0.0
//Previus central line
pcentral =0.0
//Volume accumulator in up direction
volup=0.0
//Volume accumulator in down direction
voldown=0.0

central := nz(pcentral[1])
dir := close - nz(central) >= Bandsize ? 1 : close - nz(central) <= -Bandsize ? -1 : nz(dir[1])
pcentral := ((dir == 1) and (close > central)) or ((dir == -1) and (close < central)) ? close : nz(pcentral[1])

volup   := dir==1 ? volup[1]+volume : 0
voldown := dir==-1  ? voldown[1]+volume : 0
hist = volup+voldown

plot(hist, style=histogram, color=dir==1?aqua:red, title="Accumulator", linewidth=2)
```

Comment: Inability to look at the next bar is made intentionally. This is because in realtime you cannot peek in the coming bars. Otherwise is cheating: strategies built taking into account tomorrow's trades will frustrate the trader.

Comment: So you saying there's no way to start to count from the present and go forward? Always have to add the previous data?

Comment: Yes. You can write and read variables in current bar, read variables from previous bars, but not get any data from future - that's impossible.